# Why do I get a 404 for my static webpage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, server

I’ve been working for about 2 years developing full stack apps (which were fairly mature when I get to them initially) and am starting up my first from scratch. I spent the day spinning up an EC2 instance, loading the dependencies for my stack (Postgres, golang, react), and all the other frills a shiny new machine needs (tmux, npm, vim plugins, git integration etc). I’m now stuck. 
I used create-react-app to get started on my front end and running npm start to have a build going. To see this, I can go to my instanceip:3000. 
I created golang server code which is serving up on port 8080 and I can hit my helloworld code by going to instanceip:8080/hello. 
I added an axios call in my react code to get endpoint /hello which returns a 404.

I also attempted to make my golang handle the index.js as a static page for the instanceip:8080 and that returns a 404.

How do I get my different ports to play nice? I can’t figure out what I’m missing here.

Here’s a snippet of my server code in main:

```
indexLoc := os.Genenv(webRootEnv) + "/index.html" // verified this is the correct path to my static index.html file by logging it out
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(indexLoc))
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
http.Handle("/", fs)
```

Anyone have any ideas what I’m missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're giving the path to a file (`index.html`) to `http.Dir`, which expects to be given a directory name. Maybe that could be the cause? Also, you should call `http.Handle` before `ListenAndServe`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that could be the cause:

- You're giving a file name to [`http.Dir`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Dir), which expects a directory.
- Your handler is registered after calling `ListenAndServe`, thus making it useless (http.Handle is never called)

You could fix it by changing your code like this:

```
indexLoc := os.Genenv(webRootEnv) // webRootEnv is a directory path
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(indexLoc))
http.Handle("/", fs) // register handler before listening
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

You might also want to handle the error returned from [`ListenAndServe`](https://godoc.org/net/http#ListenAndServe) to prevent silent failures of your program

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I did all these things and it's now serving from my static index.html, although this isn't being updated during my npm build (I want my app body to be replaced in there with my react code).

I'm thinking that I need some custom build script or to use a library that's already out there to get this to handle correctly??

Comment: Why is it not updated? If the files are generated somewhere else, you could also copy them over automatially. This really depends on your setup and how files are generated/built